# Rounding sharp pen tool corner illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pen-tool

I am following a tutorial and I have rounded a sharp corner made by the pen tool with effect>stylize>round corners. I am using this option as the direct selection round corner option is not possible for CS6. I am not really happy with the result though it doesnt round it as much as in the tutorial.
This is my attempt...

[image]

Also when I upped the radius it didn't increase the roundedness.

And this is the example in the tutorial...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "tutorial image" is **not** using the round corners effect.

The round corner effect has a limit, you can see that in your image. There's no way to overcome the limit without altering the underlying angle. If you increase the angle of the joint, the rounding will be smoother. The effect will only round so far and can *often* be sort of oblong for some joint angles.

The curve in your second image has either been manually created, or created via a corner rounding tool such as Live Corners in newer AI versions or the Dynamic Corners from VectorScribe plugin. It is **absolutely** not created via the Round Corners effect.

Comment: Hi @scott yes thanks for that the first image is me using the rounding corners effect as a substitute for not having a later version which uses the live corners option (second photo).

Comment: @user3413128 While similar the Round Corners effect is nowhere near as versatile, effective, or nice as Live Corners or the VectorScribe plug in.

Answer (score 4):

While it's nice to be able to use automatic rounding (Live Corners) available in the later CC versions of Illustrator, it's entirely possible to recreate nice curves manually with just the Pen tool. The rounded corner effect in CS6 is not really up to the job TBH.

Example. This was made in Illustrator CC, but I just made the curve manually with the Pen tool. This is also possible in CS6.

[image]

If you have little experience with the Pen Tool,  the [Bézier Game](https://bezier.method.ac/) is excellent for learning how to use it efficiently.